# Appending to a new row when converting from xml to csv in python

Tags: python, xml, csv, elementtree

Im having trouble writing each `control_code` along with its `description` on a new row rather than having it in the same row but different column (see image). Any ideas would be appreciated!

This is the [XML file](https://nvd.nist.gov/static/feeds/xml/sp80053/rev4/800-53-controls.xml) I'm Parsing

My Python File:

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET 
import csv


xmlFile='/Users/userName/Desktop/xmlFile.xml'
tree = ET.parse(xmlFile) 
root = tree.getroot()

# open a file for writing
excelFile = open('/Users/userName/Desktop/csvTable.csv', 'w')

# creates the csv writer object / variable to write to csv
csvwriter = csv.writer(excelFile)
# list that contains the header
list_head = []
count = 0

for element in root.findall('control'):
    list_nodes=[]
    # address_list = []
    if count == 0:

        control_code='code'
        list_head.append(control_code)

        description = element.find('.//statement/description').tag
        list_head.append(description)

        csvwriter.writerow(list_head)
        count = count + 1

    # Control Description and Control Code Parsing 
    if element.find('statement'): 
        for controlStmt in element.findall('statement'):
            value1 = controlStmt.find('description').text
            if controlStmt.find('statement') is not None:
                for part2 in controlStmt.findall('statement'):
                    value2=part2.find('description').text
                    if part2.find('statement') is not None:
                        for part3 in part2.findall('statement'):
                            value3=part3.find('description').text
                            control_code=part3.find('number').text
                            list_nodes.append(control_code)
                            description=value1+value2+value3
                            list_nodes.append(description)

                    else:

                        value3=''
                        control_code=part2.find('number').text
                        list_nodes.append(control_code)
                        description=value1+value2
                        list_nodes.append(description)
            else:
                value2=''
                control_code=element.find('number').text
                list_nodes.append(control_code)
                description=value1
                list_nodes.append(description)
    else: 
        value1=''
    csvwriter.writerow(list_nodes)
excelFile.close()
```

My Output
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Reset `list_nodes=[]` when you want a new row.  Right now you have:

```
for element in root.findall('control'):
    list_nodes=[]
        ...
        for controlStmt in element.findall('statement'):
            ...
    csvwriter.writerow(list_nodes)
```

And it should be:

```
for element in root.findall('control'):
        ...
        for controlStmt in element.findall('statement'):
            list_nodes=[]
            ...
            csvwriter.writerow(list_nodes)
```

Or more simply, skip the list.appends:

```
for element in root.findall('control'):
        ...
        for controlStmt in element.findall('statement'):
            ...
            csvwriter.writerow([control_code,description])
```

Comment: ***"more simply"***: Combine the two `findall`

Comment: The first suggestion didnt change anything, and the second suggestion im not sure what you mean by skip the append, since I want both the control code and the control description to be exported to the csv file